# Отсеять значения столбца, которые содержат одно из нескольких значений другого столбца

Tags: sql, mariadb

Примерная структура данных таблицы:

```
|   object_id   | |   risk_id |
|    111111     | |    23     |
|    111111     | |    45     |
|    111111     | |    543    |
|    222222     | |    45     |
|    222222     | |    543    |
|    333333     | |    45     |
|    333333     | |    543    |
|    333333     | |    123    |
```

Необходимо оставить уникальные `object_id`, которые не содержат в столбце `risk_id` значение 23.

Пример результата:

```
|   object_id   |
|    222222     |
|    333333     |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select object_id
  from table
 group by object_id
having sum(risk_id = 23) = 0
```

Группируем по obect_id в having суммируем записи с указанным risk_id.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    object_id
FROM
    table_name
WHERE
    object_id NOT IN (
        SELECT
            object_id
        FROM
            table_name
        WHERE
            risk_id = 23
    )
GROUP BY
    object_id
```